# How to convert string to int without using int(x)

Tags: python

Is there any other way to convert string to int? I need to do this without using this:

```
x = '345'
y = int(x)
```

Then it should work like this:

```
>>> function('456') + 5
461
```

Comment: You mean implement your own version of `int`?  The kind of thing one would be asked to do in a homework assignment?  The kind of thing you should show some effort toward solving yourself before asking here?

Comment: Why exactly do you need that?

Answer (score 1):

```
def not_int(s):
    if s.isdigit():
        return eval(s)
    raise ValueError("invalid literal: %r" % (s,))
```

Update: as posted in the comments, this only works for positive integers. It can be made to work with negative literals, but it gets more contrived for nothing, because `int` does exist! By the way, this does not even handle bases other than 10.

The following works better, and does not actually use `int` ;-)

```
def not_int(s):
    return eval("int(%r)" % (s,))
```

Comment: Hope there's no need to handle negative numbers.

Comment: You could even use `ast.literal_eval` for "safety reasons"!

Comment: For python 2.7, `eval()` and `ast.literal_eval()` works for negative ones as well.

Comment: You can't just use `eval` or `ast.literal_eval`. To work like `int` it has to raise a `ValueError` if the literal does not represent an integer.

Comment: Then use try-catch. Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `eval`, but `int` works just fine for what you are trying.

```
>>> eval('123') + 5
128
```